# Clear content of specific textfile lines without deleting the carriage return

Tags: windows, sed, replace, carriage-return

I have a DOS-Textfile from which I want to clear all content of lines that start with a pound sign. I want to Keep the carriage return (CR) in each line which does not work with the code below.

As I understand with ".*" any character except newline (LF) is regarded.  So also CR, which is why why my idea is to replace the line content with CR.

This is what I have:

```
sed.exe -e "s/^#.*/ \r/g" %1 >> result.txt
```

What I expect to happen is that for example the textfile:

```
hello you CRLF
#hello me CRLF
hello world CRLF
```

changes to

```
hello you CRLF
 CRLF
hello world CRLF
```

But the result is actually

```
hello you CRLF
 rLF
hello world CRLF
```

How can I keep the CR in the lines?

Answer (score 1):

Can you handle awk?:

Test the source file line-endings:

```
$ file file
file: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

The awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\r\n"}{sub(/^\#.*/,"")}1' file > out
```

See the result (`0d 0a` is CR LF):

```
$ hexdump -C out
00000000  68 65 6c 6c 6f 20 79 6f  75 0d 0a 0d 0a 68 65 6c  |hello you....hel|
00000010  6c 6f 20 77 6f 72 6c 64  0d 0a                    |lo world..|
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {               # set the record separators to CR LF
    RS=ORS="\r\n"     # both, input and output
}
{
    sub(/^\#.*/,"")   # replace # starting records with ""
}1' file > out        # output and redirect it to a file
```